# PHP Redirection - Header - Not working

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect to `http://www.jango.com/music/$artist/$song/video?l=0`, where `$artist` and `$song` are hopefully, the most occurring combination, extracted out of a file of which contents go like this:

```
MONSTER,PARAMORE
MONSTER,PARAMORE
DARK HORSE,KATY PERRY
```

So for that example file, the URL should be:

```
http://www.jango.com/music/PARAMORE/MONSTER/video?l=0
```

Here is the code:

```
<?PHP
$pin = $_GET["pin"];

//LOAD THE VOTES FILE
$arraypos = 0;
$concat=array("");
$file_handle = fopen("../users/" . $pin . "/votes.php", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);      
   $linelength =  strlen($line);

   $concat[$arraypos]=($line);

   $arraypos = ($arraypos + 1);
}

fclose($file_handle); 

//get all the frequencies
$frequencies = array_count_values($concat);

//make sure to sort it since array_count_values doesn't return a sorted array
arsort($frequencies);

//reset the array because you can't trust keys to get the first element by itself
reset($frequencies);

//get the first key
$winner = key($frequencies);

//find position of ,
   $positionofcomma = strpos($winner , ",");
   //dump left of , to songs
   $song = substr($winner , 0 , $positionofcomma);
   //dump right of , to artists
   $artist= substr($winner , $positionofcomma + 1); 

//refine for redirection
$find=" ";
$replace="+";
$song = str_replace ( $find , $replace , $song );
$artist = str_replace ( $find , $replace , $artist);
$search="Location: http://www.jango.com/music/$artist/$song/video?l=0";
   header($search);
?>
```

I have been trying to get this to work for hours now and I'm getting really tired. I cannot figure out where its going wrong. It might just be a silly mistake....

I'm know it gets the `$search` perfectly, It just won't redirect to it.

Comment: Just a small thing; call `exit()` after you set the header. Are there any exceptions being printed?

Comment: Any error message? Like perhaps "headers already sent"?

Comment: sometimes a space can make bugs like this check if you have a space before `<?php ` at the begining of yout file , it could be whats preventing the header from redirecting

Comment: turn on all the php debugging options. e.g. error_reporting, display_errors, etc... never work in the dark, especially when things aren't working.

Comment: im not getting any PHP error messages, but my host doesnt allways show if there is one or not. I'll upload this to another server and find out if there is any php errors.

Comment: Why do I have a sneaking suspicion that it's about `$replace="+";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$search="http://www.jango.com/music/$artist/$song/video?l=0";
header("Location: $search");
```

Or use [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on specific parts like this:

```
$search="http://www.jango.com/music/" . urlencode($artist) . "/" . urlencode($song) . "/video?l=0";
header("Location: $search");
```

Also, what is the output of this script when you run `curl -I` against it locally to see the headers?

So something like this:

```
curl -I http://yourlocalsetup/thescript.php
```

Would produce something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://www.jango.com/music/[the value of $artist]/[the value of $song]/video?l=0
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure following variable must have value:

```
if(!empty($artist) && !empty($song))
{
 header("Location: http://www.jango.com/music/$artist/$song/video?l=0");
}
```

please check variable using empty() then give in header().

Comment: hi dear, it only works when both variables have value Please review my code.